# Axios doesn't follow redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to send a post request to the server and api request should automatically redirect to payment page but when i posted request first it gives me a 302 post response and then get requests break down

so first of all is axios follow redirects automatically?
and what is wrong with my code?

```
const checkURL = (endpoint, options) => {
    if (endpoint.startsWith('http'))
        return [endpoint, options]
    else {
        if (options.headers === undefined)
            options.headers = { "Authorization": "token " + localStorage.getItem('token') }
        else
            options.headers.Authorization = "token " + localStorage.getItem('token')
        return [`${APPURL}/api/${endpoint}`, options]
    }
}



 chargeWallet=()=>{
        let params = {
            amount:this.state.walletAmount,
            customer:this.state.customerURL
        }
        try{
        post('dargah-payment/',params)
        }
        catch{

        }
    }
```

my post request

```
export const post = async (
    endPoint,
    params = null,
    options = {}
) => {
    let obj = checkURL(endPoint, options)
    if (params) {
        obj[1]['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        params = JSON.stringify(params)
    } else {
        params = {}
    }
    let promise = axios.post(obj[0], params, obj[1])
    return promise;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your post with an actual question.

Comment: _"api request should automatically redirect to payment page"_... don't do this. API requests should respond with data, not pages. Navigate to the new page in your frontend code. Also, since your request requires a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request, have you configured CORS correctly in your API?

Comment: Shouldn't your client send post request to your server and then your server redirects client to redirect.